# Cloud client config application do not get properties from Config Server Spring boot

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, build.gradle

I have a web application and I want to use Server Configuration from Spring Boot. 
Both applications are located on localhost machine. I have made first two applications from scratch and they worked together, but when i use the client that has many dependencies in it (not just the cloud-config and web dependency) it is not working anymore. How do I know? I have a variable in properties file in server and i try to use it in my client with **@Value("${atena}")** 
and error appears **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'atena' in value "${atena}"**.

The following image is my server config application.
[image]

The main class from server has the following annotation **@EnableConfigServer**

In atena-config.yml I have only the variable name:

```
 atena: 'Hellllloooooo'
```

bootstrap.yml content

```
server:
  port: 9000
spring:
  profiles:
    active: native
```

and build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server'
    runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

I am sure the server it is correct, something is wrong with my client.

--------------------> Client side

I have a restcontroller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/songs")
    public class SongController {

    @Value("${atena}")
    String variable;

    @GetMapping(value="/check-from")
    public String viewVariable(){
        return variable;
    }
}
```

in which I am trying to get the variable from server config.

bootstrap.yml from client

```
spring:
  application:
     name: atena-config
   cloud:
     config:
       uri: http://localhost:9000
```

And lastly the build.gradle from client:

```
    plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
 }

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev206-1.25.0'


    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation('org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:9.0.10')

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation('org.mybatis:mybatis:3.4.6')
    implementation('org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:1.3.2')

    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')

    implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config')
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.5'
    runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

I really don't know what happen, I am pretty sure that these dependencies are the problem, but I have not figured out which one, i can not exclude any of them, because I am using them in project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I have fixed it. Indeed the problem was from my dependencies, my gradle.build was with problem. I have created a new project with spring initializer having all the dependencies and copied the new gradle.build from there and now is it working.

This is the new build.gradle from client

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}
ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', 'Greenwich.RELEASE')
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev206-1.25.0'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.0.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
    runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```